# clear interval on mouseout

Tags: jquery, mouseover, setinterval

I'm trying to get a simple image cycle (no transitions) to work where images begin to cycle on mouseover, and stop cycling on mouseout. This works, except for stopping on mouseout. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to clear the interval:

```
var itemInterval = 750; 
var numberOfItems = $('.portrait img').length;          
//set current item
var currentItem = 0;             
//show first item
$('.pimg').eq(currentItem).show();           

$('.portrait').hover(function() {                       
    //loop through the items
    var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
        $('.pimg').eq(currentItem).hide();
        if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
            currentItem = 0;
        }else{
            currentItem++;
        }
        $('.pimg').eq(currentItem).show();
    }, itemInterval);
},
function() {
    clearInterval(infiniteLoop);
});
```

How can I get that second-to-last line working?

*Edit: fixed a couple of non-code typos*

Comment: Anyway best practices suggest not to rely on setInterval, which is inconsistent and can cause code to run not syncronized. You should instead use a function calling itself when ended with a setTimeout(). This way you can better control the function timing.

Comment: Thank you Jose. I wasn't aware of that but it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `var infiniteLoop` outside of the function, and inside the function set the timeout as `infiniteLoop = setInterval...` (without `var`). Full code:

```
var infiniteLoop;
$('.portrait').hover(function() {                       
    //loop through the items
    infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
        $('.pimg').eq(currentItem).hide();
        if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
            currentItem = 0;
        }else{
            currentItem++;
        }
        $('.pimg').eq(currentItem).show();
    }, itemInterval);
},
function() {
    clearInterval(infiniteLoop);
});
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. Is it possible to change $('.pimg') to use something like $(this 'img') instead so that I can have multiple image cycles per page? My tests using $(this).find() and $(this).children() in place of $('.pimg') are failing.

Answer (score 2):

you declared infiniteLoop inside a function, which is not avaiable inside the other anonimous function where you are calling it. Just declare that variable outside both functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a scope issue. try

```
var itemInterval = 750; 
var numberOfItems = $('.portrait img').length; 
var infiniteLoop = null;      
//set current item
var currentItem = 0;             
//show first item
$('.pimg').eq(currentItem).show();           

$('.portrait').hover(function() {                       
    //loop through the items
    infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
        $('.pimg').eq(currentItem).hide();
        if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
            currentItem = 0;
        }else{
            currentItem++;
        }
        $('.pimg').eq(currentItem).show();
    }, itemInterval);
},
function() {
    clearInterval(infiniteLoop);
});
```